# many to many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have this entity relationship:

[image: Diagram ER]

I want to save information about the current team and the last teams, also I save the different positions in each team.

I create this tables:

table of player:

```
create table player(

   codPlayer varchar(12) primary key,
   name varchar(30) unique not null,
   codCurrentTeam varchar(12),
   position varchar(20),
   foreign key (codCurrentTeam) references team(codTeam) 
);
```

table of team:

```
create table team(

   codTeam varchar(12) primary key,
   name varchar(40) unique not null

);
```

table of lastTeam:

```
create table lastTeam(

    startDate date,
    finishDate date,
    codTeam varchar(12),
    codPlayer varchar(12),
    constraint pkLastTeam primary key (codTeam,codPlayer),
    foreign key (codTeam) references team(codTeam),
    foreign Key (codPlayer) references jugador (codPlayer)
);
```

table of positions:

```
create table position(

   codPlayer varchar(12),
   codLastTeam varchar(24),
   position varchar(20),
   primary key (codPlayer, codLastTeam),
   foreign key (codPlayer) references jugador(codPlayer),
   foreign key (codLastTeam) references lastTeam(pkLastTeam)

);
```

I can create all tables except position, mysql returns the next error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

perhaps my diagram have some mistakes, but I don't know how to implement the design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can solve the issue adding a new atributte *codPlayer1* and changing *pkLastTeam* for *codTeam, codPlayer1*. 
the table would look like this:

```
create table position(

    codPlayer varchar(12),
    codTeam varchar(12),
    codPlayer1 varchar(12),
    position varchar(20),
    primary key (codPlayer, codTeam,codPlayer1),
    foreign key (codPlayer) references player(codPlayer),
    foreign key (codPlayer,codPlayer1) references lastTeam(codTeam,codPlayer)

);
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is you dont have

create table position "pkLastTeam" column in lastTeam  t

```
codPlayer varchar(12),
   codLastTeam varchar(24),
   position varchar(20),
   primary key (codPlayer, codLastTeam),
   foreign key (codPlayer) references jugador(codPlayer),
   foreign key (codLastTeam) references lastTeam(pkLastTeam)

);
```

Comment: you have define odLastTeam varchar(24) but you don't have slimier length column in any other table to match it as foreign key

Comment: I dont have a column named "pkLastTeam" because this is the name of the constraint of the primary key of the table lastTeam formed by two columns codTeam and codPlayer because that is the table between player and team

Comment: codeLastTeam is a single column and as i know you cant define foreign key in such a way to other tables composite primary key